# I am checking whether Session.cart isdefined, if not defined then defining it

Tags: cfml

```
<cfif not isDefined(session.cart)>
           <cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1)>
          </cfif>
```

1: but i am getting this error :

2: Element CART is undefined in SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with StructKeyEsxists() rather than IsDefined() and it is working finely now .

```
<cfif not structKeyExists(session, "cart")>
        <cfset session.cart = ArrayNew(1)>
       </cfif>
```

Thanks AndreasRu .

Answer (score 1):

With isdefined() you need to pass the variable name as a string in quotes. The way you are doing it, it will look for the variable name defined within the variable session.cart, thus it is throwing the error. Also, you are just creating an empty array and not populating it with data, however this depends all on how you want to populate your array in your app.. Here is one way how to do it correctly:

```
<cfif not isDefined("session.cart")>
  <!--- create empty array--->
  <cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1)>
  <!--- populate array with data at index 1--->
  <cfset session.cart[1]="some data as string"/>
</cfif>
<cfdump var="#session.cart#">
```

Here is a gist at trycf.com
https://trycf.com/gist/d872fd0c6356662a8141f3dcad7f3e90/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: isDefined("session.cart")> not working . taking it as a astring rather than array